# how to stop reading with MFRC522 using RPI

Tags: raspberry-pi, rfid, spi

I'm trying to read 2 RFID sensor at the same time or just one for 1 sec and then the other again. But when I'm reading the program does not stop until I place a tag in front the reader. So I was looking if it's possible to read 2 RC522 at the same time.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
        id, text = reader.read()
        print(id)
        print(text)     
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

and maybe do it like this

- Reader 1 using CE0
- Reader 2 using CE1

```py
reader = SimpleMFRC522()
reader2 = SimpleMFRC522()
```

[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b5VP.png)

Comment: You can use 2 readers but you will need two libraries, one for each reader. Check these posts for start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350031/dual-rc522-on-orange-pi, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615071/trying-to-use-two-mfrc522-readers-with-one-raspberry-pi-3, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43070/how-to-use-two-rfid-rc522-nfc-tag-reader-with-a-raspberry-pi. As for reading one after another, perhaps use the while loop with a time limit.

Comment: thanks for reaching out but i am still unable to make it work. The program won't continue until there is a tag in front of the first reader.